# report export no work on user's pc

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

i created a application with function export report as pdf file, the application can download the report in web format.
i run the application in my pc, it is work, but i try run at user pc, but fail when exporting

`Using _report`

```
        _report.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Report/" & "report.rpt"))
        _reportname = name & date.now

        _report.ParameterFields("name").CurrentValues.Clear()
        _report.ParameterFields("name").CurrentValues.AddValue(_name)

        _report.SetDatabaseLogon(_gstrID, _gstrPassword, _gstrDataSource, _gstrCatalog)
        _report.ExportToHttpResponse(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, context.Response, True, _reportname)
        _report.Export()

        _report.Database.Dispose()
        _report.Dispose()
```

any miss take in my code???

Comment: What do you mean by "fail when exporting"?  Is there an error message?  What exactly is failing?

Comment: the report can export as pdf in my pc, but cannot export in users pc. i use try & catch to check error, but no error message pop out. when i run in my pc, a pdf download message will pop out, but in user pc, nothing pop out

Comment: Are you sure it's not downloading?  You can configure some browsers to *not* display the download dialog.  Which browser (including version) is this failing in?

Comment: ya, 2 pc also use same broswer, i test with IE

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that *could* be happening here.

First, test it from a completely different computer that the two you have.  Test it on the same computer with the problem using a different browser.  Optionally, update your version of Adobe Reader on the misbehaving machine and try again.

Next, if you are using IIS 7.5 there is a hotfix concerning downloading PDF files ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979543 ) that impacts particular versions of the Adobe PDF Reader plug-in.

Comment: my pc no have iis, i need to install iis?

Comment: @sozai: The code you posted sends the pdf back through an HTTP context.  That is used by the web server...  Wherever this web server is, that is where you need to apply the patch.